# ASP.NET Membership Provider all user with no email

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Does the ASP.NET Membership Provider allow you to create a user with **no email address**?

I plan to still send the username and password.

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="SimpleTickConnection" applicationName="TheaterSales" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I'm not 100% sure but here's a workaround: you can remove the email field from the createuserwizard (if you're using it to register new users) and assign a custom email for all users by handling the CreatingUser event (say noemail@mysite.com).
Also, you should disable RequiresUniqueEmail in your provider (via web.config settings)

Comment: This is the obvious resolution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If using the CreateUserWizard, setting the RequireEmail to false hides the email text box and removes the email requirement.

e.g

```
<asp:createuserwizard runat="server" RequireEmail="false"> 
  <WizardSteps> 
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server"/> 
    <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server"/> 
  </WizardSteps> 
</asp:createuserwizard>
```